# Regex to remove spaces inside markdown link

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I need a way to remove spaces inside markdown formatted link as

```
[uber](https://eng.uber.com/how-uber-deals-with-large-ios-app- size/)
```

The regex should match the space and allow me to remove it. Tried with

```
/\[((?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]]|\](?=[^\[]*\]))*)\]\(\s*<?((?:[^\s\\]|\\.)*?)>?(\s)+(?:\s+['"]([\s\S]*?)['"])?\s*\)/gi
```

But not working.

Playground: https://regexr.com/5neku

Comment: just use `\s`, it will fetch every space in your string.

Comment: What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using?

Comment: @dahiya_boy That would capture space character in the title part, which I assume the OP does not want to happen.

Comment: Python or JS @41686d6564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
(\[[^][]+\])\(([^()]+)\)
```

Which looks for something of the format `[...](...)`.
This combined with a `replacer` function in `Python` could be something like:

```
import re

text = """
lorem ipsum dolor sit 
[uber](https://eng.uber.com/     how-uber      -deals-with-large-ios-app- size/)
lorem dolor
"""

# here comes the fun
def replacer(match):
    replaced = re.sub(r'\s+', '', match.group(2))
    return "{}({})".format(match.group(1), replaced)
    
rx = re.compile(r'(\[[^][]+\])\(([^()]+)\)')

text = rx.sub(replacer, text)
print(text)
```

See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/QFychX/1) and for the script itself on [**ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/BzPLvC).

---

If you want to dive deeper into the beautiful world of regular expressions and not only get your job done, you could use the following expression which is only supported by the newer `regex` module:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[[^][]+\]\()[^\s()]+\K\s+
```

This looks for something like `[...](` and then stops at every space or `)`, effectively limiting the search within the parentheses. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wXBQZH/1/).

Answer (score 1):

it easier to just capture the link, split into `[...]` and `(..)` then replace the space

```js
var links = `[uber](https://eng.uber.com/how-uber-deals-with-large-ios-app- size/)
[other link](https://eng.uber.com/    other-link)`

var m, regex = /(\[.*?\])(\(.*?\))/g;

while ((m = regex.exec(links)) !== null) {
  var UrlNoSpace = m[2].replace(/\s+/g, '')
  links = links.replace(m[1] + m[2], m[1] + UrlNoSpace)
}

console.log(links)
```